# C compile error: Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, compiler-errors, permission-denied

For some reason, when I try compiling a program, the compiler says permission denied and Id returned 1 exit status.  Could anyone tell me what that means? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>                                               /* Library inclusions */
#include "genlib.h" 
#include "simpio.h"

int binSearch(int val, int numbers[], int size1);                /* prototypes */
void sortArray (int numbers[], int size1);                       
int indexMax (int numbers[], int low, int high);
void swap (int numbers[], int loc, int loc1);
void getArray (int numbers[], int size1);
void displayArray (int numbers[], int size1);

main()
{
  int value, size1;

  printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
  size1=GetInteger(); 
  int numbers[size1];
  getArray(numbers, size1); 
  sortArray(numbers, size1); 
  displayArray(numbers, size1);
  printf("\nEnter value to find: ");
  value=GetInteger();
  binSearch(value, numbers, size1);
  getchar();
}

void sortArray (int numbers[], int size1)                        /*Function sortArray*/
{
 int i , maxInd;

 for (i= size1-1; i>=0;i--)
 {
     maxInd=indexMax(numbers, 0, i);
     swap (numbers, i, maxInd);
 }
}

void displayArray (int numbers[], int size1)                     /*Function displayArray*/
{
 int i;

 printf("This is the sorted set of numbers: \n");
 for (i=0; i< size1; i++)
 {
         printf ("%d\t", numbers[i]); 
     }
}

void getArray (int numbers[], int size1)                         /*Function getArray*/
{
 int i;

 for (i=0; i<size1; i++)
 {
     printf ("Enter the values of the %d elements: ", size1);
     numbers[i]=GetInteger();
 }
}

int indexMax (int numbers[], int low, int high)                  /*Function indexMax*/
{
int i, maxInd;

maxInd=high;
for (i=low;i<=high;i++)
{
    if (numbers[i]>numbers[maxInd]) 
    {
                   maxInd =i;
    }
    }
    return (maxInd);
}

void swap (int numbers[], int loc, int loc1)                     /*Function swap*/
{
 int temp;

 temp=numbers[loc];
 numbers[loc]=numbers[loc1];
 numbers[loc1]=temp;
}

int binSearch(int val, int numbers[], int size1)                 /*Function binSearch*/
{
 int low, high, mid;

 low=0;
 high=size1-1;
 while(low<=high)
 {
                 mid=(low+high)/2;
                 if(val<numbers[mid])
                 {
                                 high=mid-1;                
                 }            
                 else if(val>numbers[mid])
                 {
                                 low=mid+1; 
                 }   
                 else if(val==numbers[mid])
                 {
                                 printf("Your number is in location %d\n", mid+1);break;    
                 } 
                 else
                 {
                                 printf("Your value is not in the array.");        
                 }
   }
}
```

The above is the binary search algorithm code I tried to compile.

Comment: Could you please add your program and the compiler command you're using to compile it?

Comment: Do you have read permission on the source file? Do you have write permission to the directory?

Comment: This is not a programming question - but a systems operations question. At a minimum you should specify your operating system.

Comment: I'm using Dev C++ compiler, and Windows 7 as my OS.  I'm not sure about a compiler command, but to compile the program I press Ctrl F9

Comment: OH !! there is a upvote , wow :) Just google the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I may guess, the old instance of your program is still running. Windows does not allow to change the files which are currently "in use" and your linker cannot write the new .exe on the top of the running one. Try stopping/killing your program.

Comment: It still gives the same error message after killing the task.  Is there possibly something wrong with the code?

Comment: Exactly, restarting my PC solved the problem (couldn't kill manually because I couldn't find the running program in Task Manager)

Answer (score 5):

I bet for sure, that this is because **you didn't close the running instance of the program before trying to re-compile it**.

Generally, `ld.exe` returns 1 when it can't access required files. This usually includes

- Can't find the object file to be linked (or `Access denied`)
- Can't find one or more symbols to link
- Can't open the executable for writing (or AD)

The program looks completely fine, so the second point should not hit. In usual cases, it's impossible for `ld` to fail to open the object file (unless you have a faulty drive and a dirty filesystem), so the first point is also nearly impossible.

Now we get to the third point. Note that **Windows not allow writing to a file when it's in use**, so the running instance of your program prevents `ld.exe` from writing the new linked program to it.

So next time be sure to close running programs before compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Using code::blocks , I have solved this error by doing :

workspace properties > build target > build target files

and checking every project file.

Answer (score -1):

You may compiling your program while another program may be running in background.
Firstly, see if another program is running .Close it and then try ro compile.

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide some more information. Your answer looks like a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just try " gcc filename.c -lm" while compiling the program ...it worked for me

Answer (score -2):

1d returned 1 exit status error

First of all you have to create a project by clicking file  new and then project and give project name select the language c or c++ and select empty also. 
Then your program is under that project... And then give a program name save it.... Ensure that  your under some project to compile and run a program...

Comment: To what extent is that an answer to the question?

Answer (score -2):

Is a simple MAYUS word. verify the log.

Answer (score -3):

it could be that you just said main{....I use **int** main{ when I start my main.

Comment: Nope. `int` is assumed in C when no return type is specified.

Answer (score -3):

This answer is written for C++ developers, because I was haunted by such problem as one. Here is the solution:

Instead of

```
main()
{

}
```

please type

```
int main()
{

}
```

so the main function can be executed.

By the way,
if you compile a C/C++ source file with no main function to execute,
there will definitely be a bug message saying:

> "[Error] Id returned 1 exist status"

But sometimes we just don't need main function in the file,
in such a case, just ignore the bug message.

Answer (score -3):

My solution is to try to open another file that you can successfully run that you do at another PC, open that file and run it, after that copy that file and make a new file. Try to run it.

Answer (score -4):

it seems as if it comes when u have an previous compiled version of your program running

Comment: That's what the existing (4 years old) accepted answer says. Your answer adds nothing.